# Making dynamic navigations

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I just want to ask if what would I do to transfer the class attribute "active" based on the page I visit on my site.

For example [Bootstrap snippet]:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

So if I visit profile, the class is transferred into the `<li>` tag of Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/index.php'){ ?> class="active" <?php } ?>><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/profile.php'){ ?> class="active" <?php } ?>><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/message.php'){ ?> class="active" <?php } ?>><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

//we are taking demo php file like index.php,profile.php,message.php. you can use your own

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Javascript on your site, Bootstrap has some built-in functionality to do this for you.  Just make sure you have targets with resolvable id's (such as `<div id="home">`).

The biggest issue I run into with this design is that all of your "pages" are rendered at load.  I find myself having to use a lot of AJAX if I am building anything that changes based on user input.

From the bootstrap site:

> **Markup**
>   You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab" or data-toggle="pill" on an element. Adding the nav and nav-tabs classes to the tab ul will apply the Bootstrap tab styling.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```